# MUI Data table cells not reflecting API response data when I go from page 1 to 2 in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datatables, pagination

Lets say I have a parent component in inside which a **child component is there which is a MUI data table**. This child component receives API response data as props from parent component.

**Issue**
Data on the table is perfectly loaded on page load but when I move from page 1 to 2 using MUI data table pagination which passes the page number to parent and in parent component the API function is called inside useEffect() hook, which gets called when this data is received. I am able to log the API response data during pagination on the child component but these data are not loaded onto the table cells

I tired to useState() hook on the child component to set the data but it was of no help

MUI Data Table :
Page 1 of 3
[MUI Data Table Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhZTA.jpg)

[MUI Data Table Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiC25.png)

[MUI Date Table Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5eVi.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

set your pageSize={} for example pageSize={10} then all data would be shown in 10 rows or probably you are calling all your data in a single table.

```
     <DataGrid
          rows={state}
          columns={columnsFields}
          pageSize={20}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          checkboxSelection
          disableSelectionOnClick
          getRowId={(row) => row._id}
        />
```

Comment: Data are getting fetched as per pagesize set on the parent component the only thing is that they are not reflected on the MUI table

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem , the fix was simply adding

> paginationMode = "server"

```
  const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = useState({
     page: 0,
     pageSize: PAGE_SIZE,
  });

 <DataGrid
      columns={columnsFields}
      rows={state}
      rowCount={rowCountState} - //total no. of rows/dataCount
      paginationMode="server"
      initialState={{
        pagination: { paginationModel },
      }}
      pageSizeOptions={[PAGE_SIZE]}
      onPaginationModelChange={setPaginationModel}
    />
```